# I have cloudflare flexible enabled, How to redirect to https for Nginx server

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx, cloudflare

If I access directly to https it works, but the site is still accessible by HTTP. How do I force all http to https?

I have used [WordPress HTTPS plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/). But it is not redirect to https.

I have configured the nginx with following:

```
server {

    listen       xxx.x.xxx.xxx:80;
    listen       127.0.0.1:80;

    server_name mydomain.com;


    root   /var/www/html/mydomian.com/;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    charset utf-8;



    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$http_host$request_uri redirect;
  }
   ...
```

But this redirection will leads to infinite loop. I installed the
[CloudFlare Flexible SSL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cloudflare-flexible-ssl/), which said to solve the infinite loop, but still not helping.

Any other way to force the http redirect to https?

**UPDATE**

My ssl block:

```
   server {

       listen       xxx.x.xxx.xxx:443 ssl;
       listen       xxx.x.x.x:443 ssl;

    server_name  $hostname xxx.x.xxx.xxx;


    ssl                    on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl.crt/server.crt.combined;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl.key/server.key;

    root   /var/www/html;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;


    location ~^/~(?<userdir_user>.+?)(?<userdir_uri>/.*)?$ {
            alias /home/$userdir_user/private_html$userdir_uri;
            index index.html index.htm index.php;
            autoindex on;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_index index.php;

                #try_files does not work after alias directive
                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                    return 404;
                }

                fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /home/$userdir_user/private_html;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;

                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

            }
    } 



    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;

            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            #fastcgi_pass unix:/usr/local/php55/sockets/webapps.sock;
          fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

    }


    include /etc/nginx/nginx-info.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/webapps.ssl.conf;
}
```

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143193/cloudflare-and-nginx-too-many-redirects/39811248#39811248

Comment: @prosti, nope, still getting in infinite redirection loop.

Comment: The settings on cloud flare is what I would try to alter as the first thing. BTW, I used let's encrypt (free) https. You may consider that @dev-jim

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to enable https on your wordpress site.

You need to update your site urls including **https** in it if you have access to your dashboard

[image: Wordpress settings page screenshot]

You can also define both the `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` in your test **wp-config.php**

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com.mytestdomain.com' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com.mytestdomain.com' );
```

**In relation to your nginx config:**

You can use an if block instead of nesting the rewrite in your base location

```
if ($host ~* ^example\.com$) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: I did change WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME to https.  And also add the if block that you suggested. Ever since I added the if block, I got this message in FF **Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.**, which means infinite redirect loop again.

Comment: Do you have a separate location block listening on port 443?

Comment: No, I am using cloudflare free flexible ssl. So, I don't think I need that.

Comment: Is the ssl certificate installed on your server? or you're using it by turning it on from the cloudflare dashboard?

Comment: I just turn it on on cloudflare dashboard. But I just found out I have a separate block that listen to port 443. So, I just remove this block?

Comment: Can you post your ssl block for port 443

Comment: I added to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51012/discussion-between-tunji-ayoola-and-dev-jim).